# PHP count lines in a table

Tags: php, string, count, lines

The code I use to display a string inside a table (this is part of a row in a much bigger table):

```
<tr>
 <td>
 </td>

 <td colspan="6">
   <b>some data:</b>
   <br>
   <?php
    echo $proceedings; // i need to know how many lines this will take up.
    //max 28 lines
  ?>
 </td>
```

`$proceedings` can be any size and it may contain newline characters (which would make this easy) but most of the time it will contain no newline characters.
What I need to know is how many lines the string takes up in the table.
The table will always be the same width (height will automatically adjust).

Some extra information; my predecessor (this is not my code) decided to make a web page which would later be print as a PDF. This PDF needs to contain a lot of data, however on the bottom of every page (A4 format) needs to have a digital signature, so I decided to count the number of lines all the information takes up and than see if it exceeds the maximum number of lines on an A4, if so I put in the signature and continue on the next page (or in this case underneath the signature).

I know there must be other ways to create a PDF file with a nice layout however,
my PHP skills aren't that good so starting all over would probably take more time than just fixing this 'small' problem.

I hope what I have said is understandable.

EDIT:
I have decided to switch to my contingency plan I'm going to count the average number of characters that will fit on 1 line (165) and I will just divide the total amount of characters in the string by 165 and see how many lines it will produce.

If there are over 28 lines I'll create new page.

Comment: did you mean count rows in a html table ?

Comment: no i meant count the lines inside a row

Comment: Using PHP you can count no rows (<TR>). I don't think you can count the no of lines.

Comment: you should keep the count of characters in the string and also check how many characters can come in one line, on the basis of that compare them and calculate the lines

Comment: Line-feeds (be it `PHP_EOL` or `\n`) aren't converted into `<br/>` tags. They're just considered whitespace in the code, so they're irrelevant when it comes to how many lines will show up. Not sure if you can do what you want definitly (different clients, and you didn't provide any CSS rules that might apply). But do have a look at the `DOMDocument` object

Comment: @Deepanshu that was indeed my contingency plan

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem i know that's why i use nl2br to replace newline characters with <br/>

Comment: @Vinny: Where? show your full code, or at least all _relevant_ bits

Comment: The number of _rendered lines_ depends on the output medium, i.e. font size, DPI, screen resolution, font family, etc. I don't think there's an easy way to get what you want.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem believe me when i say you don't want all the code, it's horrible and irrelevant. I'm switching to my contingency plan anyway.

Comment: You might have luck by setting a max-height on the table row and defining overflow:hidden; in CSS.